# Sharing contents between `.lvt` files

Tags: input, l3build

I have many `.lvt` test files reading

```
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{...}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  ...
\ExplSyntaxOff
\input{contents}
\end{document}
```

They all `\input` the same `contents.tex` file. With that kind of test files,

```
l3build save ...
```

fails because `contents.tex` is missing.

How do I make `l3build` copy `contents.tex` to the appropriate location prior to running `save` ?

Comment: put it in the support folder?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Make that an answer?

Comment: I have tested the support folder but I can't see any change in `./build/test/`. Also `\input{../../testfiles/contents}` in not really an option.

Answer (score 2):

With the standard settings, you can use the directory `testfiles/support` inside your source area to contain 'support' files for tests. These are automatically copied into the working area for tests if they are listed as `checksuppfiles`. So something like

```lua
checksuppfiles = {"*.tex"}
```

You can then use `\input{<whatever>}` and things will 'just work'.

This technique is used for example in the `l3kernel` tests on 'backends': `d3<backend>.lvt`.

Answer (score 1):

One step further Joseph Wright's answer if your want to typeset your `.lvt` files out of the `l3build` flow (for example during development)

Assuming your `testfiles` folder contains

```
support/
  contents.tex
test.lvt
```

where `test.lvt` reads

```
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\InputIfFileExists {contents}
  {}
  {\input{support/contents}}
\end{document}
```

then you will be able to run either

```
l3build save test
```

or

```
pdflatex test.lvt
```

Another method if you can use soft links: you can gather every support files in `testfiles/support/input` and soft link `testifies/input` to this directory. Then you do not have to use the `\InputIfFileExists` command.